# Stop rsync when external drive disconnects

Tags: mount, backup, rsync

When external drive gets disconnected while rsync is doing its backup job to the external drive, rsync will continue to copy files to my local drive instead of interrupting the process, filling up the space to the very last byte.

Is there any way to change mount point permission upon disconnecting the drive? Or some clever way to prevent this?